# How to save the result of a @escaping closure function into a viewcontroller class property variable?

Tags: ios, uitableview, viewcontroller

I always get an empty value in my variable `var services:[String] = [""]` here is my code:

```
var services:[String] = [""]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    serviceList()
    print("SERVICE NOM " + services[0])
    serviceTable.delegate = self
    serviceTable.dataSource = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     print("service: " + String(services.count))
        return services.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellService", for: indexPath) as! ServiceViewCell

    //let serviceName = services[indexPath.row]


        cell.lblNomService?.text = self.services[indexPath.row]

        print("service name: " + self.services[indexPath.row])

        cell.swSelectService?.isOn = false

    return cell
}

func serviceList(){
    WebApi().listeService(){ liste, error in

        print("LISTE SERVICE VC: \(String(describing: liste?.count))")
        if (liste?.count != nil && (liste?.count) != 0){
            //print("liste: " + String(describing: liste?.count))
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                var listeServices = [""]
                var i = 0
                for row in liste! {
                    i = i + 1
                    print("service name: " + String(i) + row.nom!)
                    listeServices.append(row.nom!)
                }

                self.services = listeServices
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I tried several methods but I always get an empty value in my tableviewCell because the variable `services:[String] = [""]` despite being assigned in the function

```
func serviceList(){
    WebApi().listeService(){ liste, error in

        print("LISTE SERVICE VC: \(String(describing: liste?.count))")
        if (liste?.count != nil && (liste?.count) != 0){
            //print("liste: " + String(describing: liste?.count))
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                var listeServices = [""]
                var i = 0
                for row in liste! {
                    i = i + 1
                    print("service name: " + String(i) + row.nom!)
                    listeServices.append(row.nom!)
                }

                self.services = listeServices
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `WebApi().listeService()` is running asynchronously, so you exit `viewDidLoad()` before the data is available.

You need to call `tableView.reloadData()` *after* you set `self.services = listeServices`